# Regex replace not removing characters properly

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the regular expression:

```
const regex = /^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/
```

and its inverse (I believe) of

```
const inverse = /^(?!\d*\.?\d{0,2}$)/
```

The first regex is validating the string fits any positive number, allowing a decimal and two decimal digits (e.g. `150`, `14.`, `7.4`, `12.68`). The second regex is the inverse of the first, and doing some testing I'm fairly confident it's giving the expected result, as it only validates when the string is anything but a number that may have a decimal and two digits after (e.g. `12..05`, `a5`, `54.357`).

My goal is to remove any characters from the string that do not fit the first regex. I thought I could do that this way:

```
let myString = '123M.45';
let fixed = myString.replace(inverse, '');
```

But this does not work as intended. To debug, I tried having the replace character changed to something I would be able to see:

```
let fixed = myString.replace(inverse, 'ZZZ');
```

When I do this, `fixed` becomes: `ZZZ123M.45`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify what your desired value for `fixed` is? I think you are hoping to get `'123.45'`, but want to be sure.

Comment: Give a few examples of your input. Does it have only one number or or does it have multiple?

Comment: @elethan Yeah sorry I should have stated that. That's what I was looking to get for the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your logic here trying to find a regex that is the inverse of the regex that matches your valid string, in the hopes that it will allow you to remove any characters that make your string invalid and leave only the valid string. However, I don't think `replace()` will allow you to solve your problem in this way. From [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> The **replace()** method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.

In your `inverse` pattern you are using a negative lookahead. If we take a simple example of `X(?!Y)` we can think of this as "match X if not followed by Y". In your pattern your "X" is `^` and your "Y" is `\d*\.?\d{0,2}$`. From my understanding, the reason you are getting `ZZZ123M.45` is that it is finding the first `^` (i.e, the start of the string) that is not followed by your pattern `\d*\.?\d{0,2}$`, and since `123M.45` doesn't match your "Y" pattern, your negative lookahead is satisfied and the beginning of your string is matched and "replaced" with ZZZ.

That (I think) is an explanation of what you are seeing.

I would propose an alternative solution to your problem that better fits with how I understand the `.replace()` method. Instead of your `inverse` pattern, try this one:

```
const invalidChars = /[^\d\.]|\.(?=\.)|(?<=\.\d\d)\d*/g
const myString = '123M..456444';
const fixed = myString.replace(invalidChars, '');
```

Here I am using a pattern that I think will match the individual characters that you want to remove. Let's break down what this one is doing:

`[^\d\.]`: match characters that are not digits

`\.(?=\.)`: match `.` character if it is followed by another `.` character.

`(?<=\.\d\d)\d*`: match digits that are preceded by a decimal and 2 digits

Then I join all these with ORs (`|`) so it will match any one of the above patterns, and I use the [`g` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#using_global_and_ignore_with_replace) so that it will replace all the matches, not just the first one.

I am not sure if this will cover all your use cases, but I thought I would give it a shot. Here's a [link to a breakdown](https://regex101.com/r/dCg0E8/1) that might be more helpful than mine, and you can use this tool to tweak the pattern if necessary.

Comment: Thanks this was really insightful. I see now that my attempt at using the regex and .replace method the way I was doing was a bit of a fool's errand. I implemented your suggestion and it will cover the majority of what i was looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this

> remove any characters from the string that do not fit the first regex

Because regex matching is meant for the entire string, and `replace` is used to replace just a PART inside that string. So the Regex inside `replace` must be a Regex to match unwanted characters only, not inverted Regex.

What you could do is to validate the string with your original `regex`, then if it's not valid, replace and validate again.

```js
//if (notValid), replace unwanted character
// replace everything that's not a dot or digit
const replaceRegex =  /[^\d.]/g; // notice g flag here to match every occurrence
const myString = '123M.45';
const fixed = myString.replace(replaceRegex, '');

console.log(fixed)
// validate again
```